# Using mysql-connector-java in Flink: No suitable driver found when connecting to mysql >= 8.0.16

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, apache-flink

I am writing a simple Flink program to move data from MySQL to Mongo.

I'm using mysql-connector-java 8.0.16.

### The problem

When I try to connect to our test env DB (MySQL 8.0.15) the program works just fine. The connection string looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://my-test-db-url:3306/my_db_name
```

But once I connect it to our production DB (MySQL 8.0.16), I got:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://my-prod-db-url:3306/my_db_name
```

The only difference of these DBs is the minor version (15 vs 16).

### What I have tried

#### Upgrading test DB to match prod DB version

I upgraded my test DB to 8.0.16 to see if it's a problem with that version of mysql server. And indeed now I can't connect to test DB, too, getting the same exception.

After that I continued to upgrade both mysql-connector-java and test DB to 8.0.17, but the problem still persists.

In my other projects I can connect to those mysql DBs just fine (using spring data jpa with mysql-connector-java 8.0.18). So the db server shouldn't have any problem.

#### Manually put mysql-connector-java jar into flink/lib folder

This didn't work

#### Registering the driver manually in main class and my mysql source function's open method

no error was thrown in main class

```
// tried both
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

I also made sure after running maven package, my fat jar does contain the connector class files.

Now I'm pretty much clueless. Somebody please save me.

Comment: Maybe the driver is loaded from somewhere else (e.g. from a base module of your server)? Inspecting `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")getClass().getClassLoader()` might give you a hint

Comment: I logged the class loader, it's `org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader@3d5cea3e`. I think the driver's class is properly found and loaded since there is no exception thrown in `Class.forName()` call...

Comment: Are you running the same Flink version for dev and prod? It seems strange that one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and noticed a BUG JIRA on flink: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20540. It gives a clue:

> The baseUrl must be endswith / when instantiate JdbcCatalog.

I tried to change the baseUrl and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved same issue using `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` (I were using sqlite) before calling `DriverManager.getConnection`. It's almost same that you've tried but without calling `newInstance()`.

Comment: If the OP tried `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`, then they also did `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")`. Calling `newInstance()` is just a piece of cargo-culting that adds nothing, but also doesn't hurt.